# What are flight envelope limits of the Stearman Model 75?

Tags: aerobatics, aircraft-limitations

Recent monopropeller aerobatic aircraft such as the [Zivko Edge 540](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zivko_Edge_540) have impressive flight envelops limits (up to ±12G, $V_{NE}$ (230 kn) up to 4 times its stall speed ($V_s = 51kn$), low stall speed, ...). I would like to know how it compares with an old biplane with an open cockpit commonly used in air shows such as the [Boeing-Stearman Model 75](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing-Stearman_Model_75).

What are the flight envelops limits of the Stearman 75? I'm particularly interested in the following numbers:

- load factor limits (both negative and positive G)
- Speeds limits (both $V_{NE}$ (never exceeded speed) and $V_s$ (stall speed))

Comment: Not 12 G, that's for sure.

Comment: @quietflyer neither I expect the Vne to be as high as for the Zivko Edge 540.

Comment: I remember you have to throttle down when diving to collect speed for a loop in order not to overspeed the engine. RPM limit is at 1700.

Comment: Would the Pitts Special be a better pick for a "common airshow biplane"? It's a somewhat newer design than the Stearman, and more or less purpose-built to be a modest acro plane (vs. the Stearman, which was built to be a primary trainer first and foremost, but could also handle light aerobatic duty)

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject I haven't heard about this aircraft before reading your comment, thus I think no it is not that common in airshow. Moreover, I'm interested by biplane with open cockpit such as the Stearman.